# Limiting the tab asterisk in Slack

Tags: notifications, slack

I use [Slack](https://slack.com/) in my browser. Whenever anyone in *any* of the channels I have types a message (to me or in general), the asterisk is added.

[image]

Is there a way to limit the asterisk appearing for messages *only* in the channel I'm in/channels I want so that I don't have to check as often?

Comment: Asked Slack themselves and they said it [can't be disabled at the moment](https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/585159478057775104) but leaving this question up in case the asterisk notification can be limited to some channels, or the feature is available.

Comment: Trying out an app in the meanwhile. For Linux i'm using plaidchat https://github.com/plaidchat/plaidchat.

Answer (score 2):

You can mute a channel. Then you will no longer receive any notifications for that channel incl. the asterix for new messages.

To mute a channel open it, click on the cog and then choose "Mute XXX".
[image]

Comment: Although muting a channel also means there's no indication whether anyone has been talking there. You won't see an asterisk, & the channel won't appear highlighted (white, at time of writing) indicating people have been talking.

So basically there is no way to simultaneously not be pestered by an asterisk & also know if activity has happened at a glance, making muting of channels and disabling of notifications about as useful as leaving all channels or never opening Slack. This is actually inconsistent with direct messages, which *do* indicate activity even if you have muted them.

Answer (score 1):

I made a tampermonkey script for this:
https://gist.github.com/rchernobelskiy/d8c71e6e1ebcdd22cf897ad28da875a3

Re-pasting here if easier:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Slack tab title asterisk remover
// @namespace    http://roman.chernobelskiy/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Permanently keeps the asterisk out of slack's tab title.
// @author       Roman Chernobelskiy
// @match        https://app.slack.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    new MutationObserver(function() {
        if(document.title.indexOf('*') != -1) document.title = document.title.replace('*', '');
    }).observe(document.querySelector('title'), {
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true,
        childList: true
    });
})();
```